# idHTTP Just freezes up

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I have a button and a tmemo,  I want when i click the button it would but the result of a url into the memo.  But it freezes up any reason you can see why?

```
procedure TForm1.sendCommandClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  site : string;
begin
Memo1.Lines.Add(getContent('http://something.com'));
end;

function TForm1.getContent(url: String): String;
var
http : TIdHTTP;
begin
 http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   try
     http.HandleRedirects := true;
     Result := http.Get(url);

   finally
     http.Free;
   end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: It freezes the main thread (where UI of your app is running) and thus you may feel it's frozen. Move your task into a worker thread.

Comment: well i have let it run for 8-9 mins and still nothing in memo..should not take that long?

Comment: There's nothing what would cause such a delay in your code. It's something specific which we cannot see at this time. It might be some application blocking your request, something in your network, or the site that you query.

Comment: ok, ill try a differnt site and see if it works that way..yes it works on google..so must be something in the site..grr.. thanks TLama

Comment: You can set the `TIdHTTP.ConnectTimeout` and `TIdHTTP.ReadTimeout` properties to avoid such long delays.

Comment: something tells me its not delay due to the data on the page.. but something else not letting me read the source on the page.. just dont know what yet..

Comment: Maybe you can try to fake one of the browser's user agents. Quite a lot of servers doesn't cooperate with the Indy's one.

Comment: @TLama website is http:\\codeelf.com

Comment: I had no such delay when going to `http://codeelf.com`, even with default Indy's user agent. There is some login form, so maybe if your real URL is a site behind it, you're missing to be logged in. But that's what we can't tell without seeing the real code (URL, or sequence of URLs that you're GETting).

Comment: @Tlama what you see above is my real code  I wanted to just see if i could connect to it before using any get commands  when i go to codeelf it redirects me to `http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid/`

Comment: @TLama i could not even get login to show..can you post the code you used for that?

Comment: I didn't login to that site. I just did a GET request to `http://codeelf.com` and there was no delay. Hence I thought you were trying to GET some of the sites available after login. Btw. I've noticed your recent question. If you're just trying to login to that site, rather sniff what is POSTed to that site when you login through the browser.

Comment: @TLama thanks , i am just trying to have a UI for website / game.  Thus the site is 75% of the screen with some buttons to do stuff on the site like login, send some commands to the game..ect..

Comment: @Tlama I also was just trying to GET request to the same url with out loging in, but it freezes could it be the userAgent i am useing. Mozilla/3.0  .

Comment: I would expect that the server rejects the request rather than freeze. And I didn't have any delay when GETting the `http://codeelf.com` with default Indy user agent.

Comment: @Tlama Could you show the exact code you used to GET the page? I have no more then 5 lines of code to get in the procedure.. just want to make sure i have code that works..

Comment: I used exactly the same code as you (it is correct way to do a GET request for site with redirection) and as I said, I've noticed no delay when GETting `http://codeelf.com` with it.